# Text Date Convert issues

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, casting

I have a data source with 'datetime' that is plain text and am having issues converting it.
When I attempt to convert it to various date formats and INSERT into a new table, I am getting errors.

data example:

```
"18-07-2015 11:50:30am"
```

source table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Conv_COMMUNICATIONEXPORT]([datetime] [varchar](255) NULL)
```

destination table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TB_X_Attachment]([CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL)
```

error inserting data:

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 4
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

When I run the following select, the last convert returns an error:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 120) ,getdate()  ,CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), '01-01-2000'), 120)
```

When I run the following into the table, there is success:

```
INSERT INTO TB_X_Attachment (CreatedDate)
CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), '2000-01-01'), 120) AS WORKS
```

None of the following conversion attempts works when trying to insert:

```
SELECT      ce.[datetime] AS VARCHAR_DATETIME,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CE.[datetime], 120),
CONVERT(char(10), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CE.[datetime], 120),120),
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CONVERT(char(10), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CE.[datetime], 120),120),120),
CONVERT(VARCHAR,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CE.[datetime], 120))) ,   
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CE.[datetime], 120)
FROM        Conv_ATTACHMENTEXPORT ae
INNER JOIN  Conv_COMMUNICATIONEXPORT ce
            ON ae.[attachment record id] = ce.[communication id]
```

See image below of the results of the above convert trys
[image: last column is format that will insert]

I think if I can reverse the output to YYYY-MM-DD it may work. All the convert attempts dont want to set the format to this. How can I reverse the output to YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Welcome to the other half of the world! If you want to be able to process DMY dates then you probably need to use `SET DATEFORMAT DMY` first. That will probably be the easiest option, though when you have time components as well you will probably need some additional string manipulation to get that to work too.

Comment: use `style 103` to perform the `convert(datetime, '18-07-2015 11:50:30am', 103)`

Comment: ...Or 105 - `convert(datetime, '18-07-2015 11:50:30am', 105)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server is pretty smart when it comes to converting strings to `dateTime` values.
However, as smart as it is, string representations of date and time values are pretty tricky - that's why we have the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard which is guaranteed to always be interpreted correctly by SQL Server when converting to datetime.

However, I understand that you don't have any control over the source data, and therefor must handle the format specified.

A quick look at the [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles) table in the documentation of the `Convert` function will give you the following formats:

```
Without             With                Standard            Input/Output (3)
century (yy) (1)    century (yyyy)  

3                   103                 British/French      3 = dd/mm/yy
                                                            103 = dd/mm/yyyy

4                   104                 German              4 = dd.mm.yy
                                                            104 = dd.mm.yyyy

5                   105                 Italian             5 = dd-mm-yy
                                                            105 = dd-mm-yyyy
```

Any one of the three options with century would give you a correct value of `DateTime` for the specified string:

```
DECLARE @DateString varchar(30) = '18-07-2015 1:5:3pm';

SELECT  @DateString As string, 
        CONVERT(DateTime2, @DateString, 103) As [103], 
        CONVERT(DateTime2, @DateString, 104) As [104], 
        CONVERT(DateTime2, @DateString, 104) As [105]
```

Result:

```
string                  103                     104                     105

18-07-2015 1:5:3pm      2015-07-18 13:05:03     2015-07-18 13:05:03     2015-07-18 13:05:03
```

Since the original string use hyphens as a separator, I would go with the Italian standard (105) because it's the closest to the source string format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select convert(datetime, [datetime], 105)
```

where `[datetime]` is your varchar column which has the date to be converted

or simply

```
select convert(datetime, '18-07-2015 11:50:30pm', 105)
```